# Can I have relative sectioning: Chapter +1 Section +1 Subsection -2 Chapter again

Tags: sectioning

I found myself changing text between sections and parts and between a document with chapters and another only with sections.

This means converting chapters and sections to sections and subsections and vice versa. Is there a way to avoid this? I thought about having relative sectioning, where you would just tell latex to go one level down or one up, and so copy paste would also work.

I couldn't find additional information but some people here talked about similar concepts: [her](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12005/69635) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266525/how-to-tell-if-last-sectioning-command-was-chapter-section-subsection/266534#266534).

Comment: isn't http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266525/how-to-tell-if-last-sectioning-command-was-chapter-section-subsection/266534#266534 what you looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure @touhami, that code is too advanced for me (as the original question) . Would I be able to jump from subparagraph to section, or use only chapters and below?

Comment: your problem is : you have a document A with `parts` and `section`, a document B with `section` and `subsection` and you want to merge both, while the `part`s of document A have the same hierarchical level than `section`s of document B, right ?

Answer (score 3):

The `memoir` class enables you to easily change between a document style with chapters or one without.

```
\documentclass[...,
%article,    % uncomment this option for article style
...]{memoir}
....
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{A section}
...
```

Without the `article` option `memoir` gives a `book` or `report` style headings but with the `article` option a `\chapter` is set like a `\section` a `\section` is set like a `\subsection` and so on. In essence always use `\chapter`, `\section` etc and by simply using the `article` option it will be typeset like an article, not as a report.

Comment: I'm using `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}` for one and `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}`. Could I still use memoir? I think this is a good alternative, if an exact answer to my question doesn't exist.

Comment: Use `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}` for one and `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn,article]{memoir}` for the other.